# VBA code for comparing 2 numbers gives different results

Tags: excel, vba

I have the last line below containing sum of above cells (7,6). This is a formula like this: `=SUM(E6:E26)`

Furthermore, I do code some vba to set in red whenever valid is not equal to 7.6. What is strange is sometimes the SUM value is not considered as 7,6 even if it is. Then sometimes it is red and should be black.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
            If (Cells(TABLE_TOTAL_ROW, curCol).Value = 7.6) Then
                ''' Set text in black (automatic)
                With Cells(TABLE_TOTAL_ROW, curCol).Font
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            Else
                ''' Set text in red
                With Cells(TABLE_TOTAL_ROW, curCol).Font
                    .Color = -16776961
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
```

Below: I set a breakpoint: in the Immediate window, I get the value of `7,6`. Below that, I compare and it returns false

[image]

Very strange for me.

Comment: 7,6 is not equal to 7.6. So, the comparison should return False isn't it?

Comment: As you can see on the picture sometimes it returns true (7,6 in black) sometimes it returns false (7,6 in red) strange isn't?

Comment: Yes. That is strange. Since the value 7,6 is an absolute, why don't you convert the cell value to a string and do a string comparison against '7,6' just to be sure. I guess that would give you much more predictable answer. You can even convert both operands of comparison to string if you have to find them dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare floating point values for equality, due to the fact that certain values cannot be represented exactly.

```
7.6 is probably 7.5999999 (or similar)
```

The 7.6's that don't match are being displayed rounded.

Use a tolerance instead:

```
if Abs(x - y) < tolerance
```

where tolerance is a value like 0.000001

Comment: Your solution did the job. Thanks.